# quiz results not showing in Moodle 4.1

Tags: php

I have used the quiz plugin for showing results but when click on Quiz button then click on the popup, so after is showing Database read error

So, I have used the quiz plugin using version 3.11.1 (Build - 2022062300), but its quiz results do not show in Moodle 4.1.

Please check the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/lsSx4gO_G6Gz

So please solve my problem, I am waiting for your response.

Regards,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: i do curious are you writing your own plugin or using [existing one](https://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=28)? if its the later, it might be better to ask on the official forum instead of stackoverflow. we mostly discuss about programming problem. those being said, you should check which query it fails (via mysql log) and see if any [previous discussions](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/view.php?id=737) relevant to your problem.